# How to horizontally center a button within a NAV element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me stress that I'm no developer/coder at all and have almost no knowledge of code (even html). Yet I'm faced with a task to build a ABtest for certain pages of our website, using Virtual Webite Optimizer and need some help.
I have an iFrame topbar containg three elements - a logo on the left, a text-string (title) in the center and a button on the right. For the purpose of the text (to create the test variation) I need to "swap" the text with the button, ie. need the button in the center and the text-string on the right. Of course, I can drag the button within the VWO wysiwyg editor, but that way, the button became absolutely-placed and it will not be centered when displayed on different resolutions/devices. So how do I do this through the code? When I display the html code for the individual elements, I get this:

NAV

```
<nav class="simple-top-bar"> <div class="simple-top-bar__title"> <a class="logo vwo_1489874617112" href="http://Specimen.info" title="Specimen.info"> <img alt="Specimen.info" height="36" src="http://picture.net/pictures/logos/stickybar/xyz.svg"><span class="hide-for-small-only">Specimen.info</span> </a> </div> <a href="http://www.specimen.info/specimen/specimen" class="button button--primary button--noshadow medium right vwo_1489874134345 vwo_1489927072017" data-contact-button="" data-form-mr="specimen" data-form-name="Specimen" data-form-channel="1" data-form-source="outframe">Contact us</a> <div class="simple-top-bar__center show-for-medium vwo_1489927071979 vwo_1489873911537">Specimen</div> </nav>
```

Text (which I need to be aligned right)

```
<div class="simple-top-bar__center show-for-medium">Specimen</div>
```

Button (which I need to be horizontally centered):

```
<a href="http://www.link.info/specimen/specimen" class="button button--primary button--noshadow medium right" data-contact-button="" data-form-mr="specimen" data-form-name="Specimen" data-form-channel="1" data-form-source="outframe">Contact us</a>
```

Thank you so much in advance for helping the noob out!

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt about positioning, use... flexbox!

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center; /* Depends */
}
```

Oh, and by the way, I would appreciate if you didn't fit all of the code on one line. It's hard to read.

---

Another way is to use `float`.

```
#logo {
    float: left;
}
#text {
    float: right;
}
#button {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The `#logo` and the `#text` will behave as exactly as absolute positioned in the way that they will be taken out of the normal flow.